# How to increment a single number in a text file with PHP

Tags: php

I am writing a VoteBox (like/dislike box) in html and I cannot find how to do this anywhere.

Basically, there will be a like and a dislike button. When one of them gets clicked, it will forward the user to a page. And in that, I want some PHP code that will increase the number in upvotes.txt/downvotes.txt

I have tried doing it with a database but the problem is I want anyone to be able to use this without any setup.

i also want the front page to display the number of upvotes and the number of downvotes

so its kinda like this (most of this isn't real code BTW im new to PHP):

```
//this is the code for upvote.html
$upvotes = get_data_from_TXT_file

$changedupvotes = $upvotes + 1

set_data_in_txt_file_to_$changedupvotes
```

Sorry if i havent explained this very well

Any help appreciated

Comment: it's a good idea to use xml structured file instead of text.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`file()`](http://php.net/file) to read the file into an array, and then increment the upvotes, and then write the data back using [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents):

```
if (file_exists('upvotes.txt')) {

    $content = file('upvotes.txt'); // reading all lines into array
    $upvotes = intval($content[0]) + 1; // getting first line
    file_put_contents('upvotes.txt', $upvotes); // writing data

} else {

    // handle the error appropriately

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is skeleton of the code that you can use:

```
$file = 'file.txt'; // your file name
// error handling etc to make sure file exists & readable

$fdata = file_get_contents ( $file ); // read file data

// parse $fdata if needed and extract number
$fdata = intval($fdata) + 1;

file_put_contents($file, $fdata); // write it back to file
```

**Reference:**

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php